# Can a cached map service automatically Track feature class changes and update only the changed locations

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, esri-geodatabase, generate-tiles

Is there any option I can enable in an arcgis 10.2 cached map service, so as to automatically update the tiles for the locations that have been changed ?

If it is not that simple, I suppose I will have to:

> Target your cache updates to cover only the areas where data was edited ([as described here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Map_caching_on_demand/01540000045s000000/))

and as referred here to :

> create a custom tool to track all the changes since the last update, then export these changed areas to a feature class and update tiles based on the feature class boundary.

However how could I track the changes in the feature class ?

Comment: Did you find any solution to achieve  ? I m stuck at the same point.

Comment: Im afraid not. Currently i have created a custom java scheduler that runs once a day, which is updating my cached services. The scheduler sends http requests to the <gis server url>/arcgis/rest/services/System/CachingTools/gpserver/manage map server cache tiles/submit job

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  I have checked that, and seems i would have to do it same way.